# How to detect toggling of the fullscreen-toolbar in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile page with a fixed full-screen toolbar, where `data-tap-toggle` is enabled.

Straight under the toolbar i have positioned a banner which should slide upwards when the toolbar is hiding and slide downward when the toolbar is showing.

jQuery Mobile toggles the `toolbar` by applying and removing the `ui-fixed-hidden` class - sadly, i can't find in the documentation of the `toolbar` widget any `toggle`, `hide` or `show` event for that.

How can i detect when the `toolbar` is toggled, to reposition my banner?

```css
.banner {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  top: 46px;
  min-height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-one">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true">
      <h1>First Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <div class="banner">call-to-action</div>
    </div>
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true">
      <h3>Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**:

Extend `mobile.toolbar` widget.

```
$.widget("mobile.toolbar", $.mobile.toolbar, {
  toggle: function() {
    this[this._visible ? "hide" : "show"]();
    if (this._visible) {
      /* visible */
    } else {
      /* hidden */
    }
  }
});
```

**Solution 2**:

Listen to animation end events.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function() {
  $(".ui-header").on("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", function(e) {
    /* do something */
  });
});
```

> **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9awk01ek/1/)**